# controllerDidChangeContent not called

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My app is quite simple: a TableViewController displays the content stored in Core Data. An add button pushes a second view modally which allows me to save stuff into Core Data. I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate the main VC. If I save stuff to Core Data and present the main view controller again, my tableView doesn't refresh its data. I think it is because the delegate methods are not called. Any idea why?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController!
lazy var coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.setToolbarItems(toolBar().cons, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "CDPodcast")
    let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "artist", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
    managedContext = coreDataStack.context
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if (!fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error)) {
        println("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

None of the below are called

```
 func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    println("change section")
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    println("begin updates")
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    println("end updates")
}
```

Edit: More code

```
 func saveToCoreData(name: String, artist: String, summary: String, feedURL: String, artworkURL: String, date: NSDate, episodes: [MWFeedItem]) {
    self.managedContext = coreDataStack.context
    let podcastEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CDPodcast", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    currentPodcast = CDPodcast(entity: podcastEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    currentPodcast.name = name
    currentPodcast.artist = artist
    currentPodcast.summary = summary
    currentPodcast.feedURL = feedURL
    currentPodcast.artworkURL = artworkURL
    currentPodcast.date = date


    let episodesEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("CDEpisode", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
    for var i = 0; i < episodes.count; i++ {
        let episodesToSave = CDEpisode(entity: episodesEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.managedContext)
        var episode: AnyObject = currentPodcast.episode.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet

        println("There are \(episodes.count) items in the episodes array")
        episodesToSave.title = episodes[i].title
        episodesToSave.downloadURL = episodes[i].enclosures[0].valueForKey("url") as! String
        episodesToSave.showNotes = episodes[i].summary
        episode.addObject(episodesToSave)
        currentPodcast.episode = episode.copy() as! NSOrderedSet
    }


    self.coreDataStack.saveContext()

}
```

Comment: Are the changes made against `CDPodcast` entity?

Comment: Yes, I am saving changes made made in 2 different entities in 1 managed context.

Comment: Share the code please.

Comment: Updated! Thanks. This function is called when someone presses a button. The root view controller is then presented.

Comment: did you implement `func controller(controller:, didChangeObject:, atIndexPath:, forChangeType:, newIndexPath:)`? As far as I know NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate only works if all 4 "delegate did change something" methods are implemented.

Comment: I've implemented it now. Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea please?

Comment: Are you certain that a) the context in saveToCoreData is the same as the context for your fetchedResultsController - is CoreDataStack a singleton?  and b) your saveToCoreData is being called?

Comment: Thanks pbasdf. a) Yes it is. and yes it is a singleton. b) my method is being called. If I quit the app and restart it, the tableView will update and will be filled correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with this was that my ManagedObjectContext wasn't being passed around properly. `println(context)` returned different memory addresses between the App Delegate and View Controller #3. I didn't find a proper way to fix this so I am just passing the context between view controllers. Having the right context fixed it.

Comment: I got the exact same issue. I read through this Apple sample project [Earthquakes: Populating a Core Data Store Using a Background Queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Earthquakes/Introduction/Intro.html) (at this time, they have updated the project to Swift 4) and found that they set `container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true` at line 59 when initiating `lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer` in QuakesProvider.swift. This helps sync between different contexts.